# ul#menu li a:visited {color: yellow; } not working

Tags: php, css

```
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  </head>
  <body >      
        <?php
                 echo '<ul  id="menu">
                <li><a href= "first.php">first</a></li>
                <li><a href= "second.php">second</a></li>
                <li><a href= "third.php">third</a></li>
                </ul>';
        ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

This list.php is separate file.i have included this in my pages and trying to highlight the currentpage clicked using a:active but it is not working..help me out in this

```
<div class= "main-menu" id= "main-menu">    
            <?php include 'includes/list.php';?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

a:active is the state when you click on the link. (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp)

a:visited is the state if you clicked on the link before. (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp)

You can add a class ("current" in this example) to highlight your current link

```
<li><a href="first.php" class="current">first</a></li>
```

And with css:

```
.current {
    color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Its not working and i have list of 26(more will be added in future) and  adding class to all link is a good way?

Comment: You only add the class to the link you want to highlight. Can you show the code that isn't working?

Comment: .current{
 color:black;} <li><a href= "last.php" class= "current">Last</a></li>

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jquery, then you can use this solution:

The js script should be common in all the pages i.e. first.php, second.php,etc.
Below is the code:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  </head>
  <style>
  .active{ color:yellow; }
  </style>
  <body >      
        <?php
                 echo '<ul  id="menu">
                <li><a href= "first.php">first</a></li>
                <li><a href= "second.php">second</a></li>
                <li><a href= "third.php">third</a></li>
                </ul>';
        ?>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('ul#menu li a').click(function() {
        $('ul#menu li a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
</script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Hope, this will help you.

Comment: Find my updated answer, i hope your problem will be solved through this.

Comment: .active class & the footer script should be common in all the pages, then only it will work

Comment: yes it is common because it is included in all page and one more problem is that if i use your script am not able to view table using datatables script

Answer (score 0):

i found your problem
in your li tag you should check anchor tag and check first.php page actually exists or not
it means : href="../first.php" that is your solution

but your code is like this means first.php not exists thats why the css not working properly

first

i hope you understand what i actually told you